Electron shell transition and locality
So I'm just now starting to learn quantum physics, so I don't know very much.
What I do however (think I) know, is that the wave function for an electron around the atom can instantaneously transition from one distribution to another.
The issue I have with this is how each constituent part of the wave function synchronizes so that this can happen.
What I mean is, thinking from an information perspective, if some part of the cloud comes in contact with a photon and absorbs it, it somehow has to communicate to the rest that it's time to knock up an energy level.
For example, an event on the left side of the atom could instantaneously change the state of the right side.
Maybe it turns out like entanglement where you can't actually detect the change in such a way to communicate.
I don't know, talking to my physics professor wasn't particularly enlightening either.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

An isolated quantum system described by a wavefunction governed by an equation of motion, such as the Schrodinger equation:
$$i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}\Psi (\mathbf{r},t)=\left[-{\frac {\hbar ^{2}}{2m}}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf{r},t)\right]\Psi (\mathbf{r},t)$$
The wavefunction changes continously over space and time. A measurable quantity such as energy is described by a Hermitian operator called an observable. For energy the operator is just the one operating on the right hand side of the equation above which is called the Hamiltonian.
According to classical physics, a measurable quantity like energy has some value $E(t)$ and if you measure the energy you just get the number $E(t)$. In quantum physics the energy is described by an observable that can be represented by a matrix not a single number. That matrix in conjunction with the state gives the expectation value of the observable. If the possible values of energy are $E_1,E_2\dots$ then the expectation value is
$$\langle E\rangle=\sum_jp_jE_j$$
where $p_j$ is the probability of the $j$th value. There are states called eigenstates in which the expectation value of an observable is equal to one of its values and it is said to be sharp.
In general the motion of a quantum system depends on what is happening to all of its possible states: this is called quantum interference. If information is copied out of a system during interference the interference is suppressed: this effect is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
Some systems like the objects large enough for you to see in everyday life interact with the environment far more quickly than they change and as a result interference is very heavily suppressed for them and it looks like they are in just one location on the relevant scales. This isn't true for electrons in atoms: they interact relatively weakly with the outside world and decoherence selects states that are sharp in their energy (energy eigenstates)  $\psi_{E_j}(\mathbf{r})$ as their stable states:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811026
I have dropped the $t$ because energy eigenstates don't change over time.
These energy eigenstates vary continuously over space and they are sometimes depicted in books as having shapes like dumbells or spheres or whatever. Changing from one energy eigenstate to another just involves the electron wavefunction changing over time at each location from the value of one $\psi_{E_j}(\mathbf{r})$ to the value of another $\psi_{E_j}(\mathbf{r})$. This happens locally by changes at one place propagating through space to another place. There is no instantaneous change, only gradual and local change according to the relevant equations of motion. This may happen very quickly on the scales of time we are used to but the changes are continuous. While the change is happening the electron is in a superposition of both states and if you were to measure its energy you would find that the state is unsharp. The full theory of how this happens is more complicated than this and is described by quantum field theory, see "Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur" by Lancaster and Blundell for an introduction.
There are physicists trying to simulate and measure changes in electron states in real time:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.02111
Some of the answers above claim that quantum theory is non-local. The equations of motion of real quantum systems are local. The theories that are non-local are variants of quantum theory that modify the equations of motion either explicitly or implicitly and none of those theories are currently incapable of reproducing the tested predictions of relativistic quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Unfortunately it is common for people discussing quantum theory to obfuscate what quantum theory implies about the world and whether it is an accurate description of how the world works. Many undergraduate textbooks teach you some of the maths but are quite bad at explaining the actual physics but they are okay as long as you take what they say with a grain of salt, e.g. "Introduction to quantum mechanics"  by Griffiths and Schroeter.

There are two things to note here.
One, non-locality is ubiquitous in quantum mechanics.  Einstein pointed this out by talking about a spherical particle detector and noting that all parts of the detector must know simultaneously whether a particle has been detected somewhere, which is a very similar argument to what you're making here.  And Bell's theorem confirms that, barring the possibility of a many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, the world as described by quantum mechanics is definitively non-local.  So we just have to get used to the fact that locality is not a fundamental principle of the universe (or else accept that many-worlds is true, though even that doesn't help us very much because no one has yet been able to formulate a completely local version of many-worlds).
Two, in reality, the transition of an electron to a different state is not completely instantaneous.

The issue I'm having here is that I'd heard one of the major downsides of hidden variable theories is that they violate locality, implying that normal QM doesn't.
And also, if QM really does violate locality (and commonly too), how do relativistic theories like QFT reconcile with it?

Normal QM does violate locality, very obviously:  upon measurement, the wave function collapses everywhere simultaneously.  This is true also of QFT.  The point of Bell's theorem is to ask whether locality can be saved by introducing new variables, and the answer turns out to be no.  How that relates to the issue of relativity isn't a fully resolved problem.  Some theories (like Bohmian mechanics) get rid of relativity at the fundamental level.  Others (like GRW with flash ontology) manage to keep Poincare invariance while being nonlocal.

Well, quantum mechanics with wave functions is non-relativistic, so there's no mechanism to prevent FTL.
Now you claim the transition is instantaneous--I don't know about that. It's safe to say it takes:
$$ \Delta t = \frac{\hbar}{\Delta E} $$
but that is not based on any time-evolution equation.
The M.O. in quantum mechanics is to deal with approximate eigenstates of a hamiltonian, and then have a perturbing interaction hamiltonian drive transitions via Fermi's Golden Rule--so there is no mechanism to address your question.
We don't have exact states for the atom in the presences of a dynamic EM field, so we do perturbation theory. I don't even know if you could solve it numerically with standard time evolution, or if you would learn anything from that.
In quantum optics, the transition can be treated with creation and annihilation operators, where the initial state electron is annihilated, and the final state electron is created, and the appropriate photon operator for absorption or emission is included.
Again, there's no way to address your question. IMHO, it's a far too classically inspired question to be asking: so just don't.
Keep learning quantum.

Well, as far as I'm aware quantum theories still use absolute spatial coordinate systems (no uncertainty in coordinates), and any influence that propagates through said coordinate system faster than light can travel is in conflict with relativity, which is pretty bad, usually.
I don't see how thinking more quantum makes this issue seem less important.

Newtons laws are also in conflict with relativity--but we 1) still use them on billion dollar projects 2) don't have an existential crises over them.
